# What does this snippet of code in the children variable array mean?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, breadth-first-search

```
def breadth_first_search(adj_matrix, source_index, end_index)
  node_queue = [source_index]
  puts "#{source_index} stored into queue \n"

  loop do
    curr_node = node_queue.pop
    puts "#{curr_node} popped \n"
    return false if curr_node == nil
    return true if curr_node == end_index

    children = (0..adj_matrix.length-1).to_a.select do |i| 
      adj_matrix[curr_node][i] == 1

    end

    puts "children: #{children}"
    node_queue = children + node_queue
    puts "node_queue: #{node_queue}"
  end
end
```

I can understand what it does conceptually, but the actual syntax is what I don't understand. Is the children variable an array that stores elements with a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `children` is being set to the result of the enumerable method [select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)

`select` is a method often called on an array which takes a block. The return value is only the values of the original array in which the block returns a `truthy` object (e.g. not `false`, not `nil`)

`(0..adj_matrix.length-1)` is a range object, from 0 to the length of `adj_matrix`, which is converted to an array via `to_a` (resulting in `[0, 1, 2, ...]`)

Then that array is filtered by `select` to only be the values in which `adj_matrix[curr_node][i] == 1`. So if the nodes at index `0` and `2`, are equal to `1`

then the result would be `[0, 2]`